# Why does Vim only activate my highlight configuration after I source my .vimrc manually?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I was cleaning up my [vimrc](https://github.com/msuriar/dotfiles/tree/master/vim) today, splitting it into separate files to make it easier to maintain. On completion of these changes, all my configuration, mappings and plugins appear to be working, except for highlighting trailing whitespace.

I have the following lines in .vim/rc/appearance.vim:

```
highlight RedundantSpaces term=standout ctermbg=red guibg=red
match RedundantSpaces /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/ "\ze sets end of match so only spaces highlighted
```

As I understand it, the first line creates a highlight group 'RedundantSpaces', and instructs vim to make the background of any text matching the highlight group red, when on a colour terminal. The second line defines the pattern used to identify text matching the highlight group.

When I open a file in vim and start typing spaces on a blank line, they are not highlighted in red. If I run `:source ~/.vimrc`, the highlighting appears.

If I remove the lines sourcing all my individual `rc/*.vim` files from `.vimrc` and put the above two `RedundantSpaces` lines in `.vimrc` directly, vim behaves as expected, and trailing whitespace is highlighted.

However, if I leave in the lines sourcing `rc/*.vim`, and then have the `RedundantSpaces` lines at the end of my `.vimrc` (i.e. those commands are the last to be run when vim is invoked), the highlighting still does not work, and I need to `source ~/.vimrc`.

It seems clear that something in my `rc/*.vim` files is interacting poorly with the highlighting configuration, however I'm at a loss to explain what that is. Nothing in any of those files should be interacting with the highlight configuration.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Your `.vimrc` isn't in the repository, nor `./rc.local/`. Check if you set any `guioptions` after sourcing `appearance`.

Comment: @Sukminder rc.local doesn't exist in the repository deliberately; it's for things that I want to configure which shouldn't be in version control.

.vimrc is called 'vimrc' in the root of the directory I linked. I leave the trailing . off so that the file isn't hidden; I create a symlink when I actually install it.

Comment: OK. Thanks for explanation. Makes sense now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [sensible plugin:line 93](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/blob/master/plugin/sensible.vim#L91). `:help t_Co`

```
" Allow color schemes to do bright colors without forcing bold.
if &t_Co == 8 && $TERM !~# '^linux'
  set t_Co=16  " << --- Causes hickup
endif
```

If you run vim in verbose log mode (`vim -V15load_log.vim`) – and search
for `t_Co=` and `RedundantSpaces` you'll see that `sensible` is actually parsed *after* your `appearance.vim` file.

Quick fix would be to either comment out that section of the code and add it to your `.vimrc`, but as you link to git repositories that is perhaps not what you want.

A different approach would be to move it out of the `bundle`directory and add it as a separate `source` line in your `vimrc`, ***before*** your glob loop.

I.e.:

```
  source ~/.vim/hacks/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim

  for f in split(glob ...
```

Another way would be to load custom highlight on BufLoad.

Etc. …

Comment: Excellent, thanks. So, my next question - why is sensible.vim parsed after my glob loop? Does that mean that any plugins managed by pathogen are actually set up *after* my .vimrc has been processed?

Comment: Good question. I haven't looked to deep at `pathogen` and load routine. It could be the load sequence of vim itself as well. Best bet is to run with various verbose levels and look et logs. Or try benchmark debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NeoBundle then using `NeoBundleLazy 'tpope/vim-sensible'`, then `NeoBundleSource` at the end of your vimrc does the trick. Also see https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/issues/74.